# Reading difficult text file in python: no spaces and split numbers in lines

Tags: python-2.7

I've been stuck in how to read the following text file --> [Extract of the text file I would like to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5r14.png) <-- in Python. This file contains 374 numbers per line, and in total 201 lines. However, the file has the following inconveniences:

1) Numbers are not separated by white spaces or any other delimiter.

2) The first number of each line always doesn't have the first 0 (for instance, it is written .15 instead of 0.15).

Do you have any ideas or solutions of how to read this file in Python? I had never have to deal with such as difficult text file (and I receive the text files from another person, and I cannot ask that person to save the data again).

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like numbers in "scientific notation", with two-digit exponents. In your sample it looks like there's never a zero or other digit before the decimal point. Try reading them like this:

```
with open("file.txt") as inp:
    text = inp.read()
numbers = re.findall(r"[.\d]*?D[+-]\d\d", text)
```

If you want to convert the number strings to floats:

```
values = [ float(n.replace("D", "e")) for n in numbers ]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I also found another solution with the function getfromtxt of bumpy, specifying the length of the numbers as delimiter.

Comment: @GuadalupeCañas Did you test this code? It doesn't work for me. (The issue is that it's not matching the `+` in the numbers.)

Comment: Oops, indeed, I accidentally left the "+" out of the regexp; fixed now (but easy to fix for anyone who can do regexps).